# How can I reach the scope of the $fileName variable after the else statement?

Tags: php, html

I would like to find a way to access the file in the else statement but the $fileName scope is local. How can I make it global in both statements?

```
<?php
        if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == ''){
    
            $session = rand(1000000, 9999999);
            $fileName = $session;
            $idfile = fopen("$fileName.txt", "w");
            fclose($idfile);
            indexform($session);
    
        }else{
    
            $support = $counter + $support - 1;
            $counter = $support;
    
            if (fsize($idfile) != 0){
                $idfile = fopen($fileName, "r");
                $difficulty = fgets($idfile);
                $number = fgets($idfile);
                $counter = fgets($idfile);
                fclose($idfile)
                $counter++;
            }
            
            $idfile = fopen("$fileName.txt", "w");  
            fputs($idfile, $difficulty);
            fputs($idfile, $number);
            fputs($idfile, $counter);
            fclose($idfile);
            form($counter);
    
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare it, outside the if/else statement.

Take a look at this reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php